# How to run current buffer as python module from project root in Elpy mode?

Tags: python, elpy

Take for example I have the following project tree.

```
repo
|
+-root
  |
  +-__init__.py
  +-__main__.py
  +-packageA
    |
    +-__init__.py
    +-__main__.py
```

My buffer is currently at `root.packageA.__main__`. Due to relative imports within the code, it is necessary to run `python -m root.packageA` from `repo`.
How do I do so using `elpy` commands?

Comment: Do you use `projectile` too?

Comment: @Swedgin I do not use it directly, but it's a requirement for `elpy`

Comment: I read your question wrong. But in projectile you can define a root project folder for each project and have seperate commands saved to compile/run/test the project by using `.dir_locals.el`. I don't know if that make things easier for you.